# Cleaning up dates (years, specifically) with regex

Tags: regex, r

I have database with an non-validated year field.  Most of the entries are 4-digit years but about 10% of the entries are "whatever."  This has led me down the rabbit hole of regular expressions to little avail.  Getting better results than what I have is progress, even if I don't extract 100%.

```
#what a mess
yearEntries <- c("79, 80, 99","07-26-08","07-26-2008","'96  ","Early 70's","93/95","late 70's","15","late 60s","Late 70's",NA,"2013","1992-1993")
#does a good job with any string containing a 4-digit year
as.numeric(sub('\\D*(\\d{4}).*', '\\1', yearEntries))
#does a good job with any string containing a 2-digit year, nought else
as.numeric(sub('\\D*(\\d{2}).*', '\\1', yearEntries))
```

The desired output is to grab the first readable year, so 1992-1993 would be 1992 and "the 70s" would be 1970.

How can I improve my parsing accuracy?  Thanks!

EDIT: Pursuant to garyh's answer this gets me much closer:

```
sub("\\D*((?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!\\-|\\d)|\\d{4}).*","\\1",yearEntries,perl=TRUE)
# [1] "79"        "07-2608"   "07-262008" "96"        "70"        "93"        "70"        "15"        "60"       "70"        NA          "2013"      "1992"
```

but note that, while the dates with dashes in them work with garyh's regex101.com demo, they don't work with R, keeping the month and day values, and the first dash.

Also I realize I didn't include an example date with slashes rather dashes.  Another term in the regex should handle that but again, with R, it doesn't not produce the same [(correct) result](https://regex101.com/r/dQ4vR2/3) that regex101.com does.

```
sub("\\D*((?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!\\-|\\/|\\d)|\\d{4}).*","\\1","07/09/13",perl=TRUE)
# [1] "07/0913"
```

These negative lookbacks and lookaheads are very powerful but stretch my feeble brain.

Comment: the first entry--`"79, 80, 99"`--what do you want? All 3 years?

Comment: ditto `"93/95"` and `"1992-1993"`

Comment: Provide your desired result for this sample input. And note that regular expressions are best when your data has some "regularity." An "anything goes" type of field is not easy to program against.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what flavour of regex R uses but this seems to get all the years in the string

```
/((?<!\d)\d{2}(?!\-|\d)|\d{4})/g
```

This is matching any 4 digits *or* any 2 digits provided they're not followed by a dash `-` or digit, or preceded by another digit

see [demo here](https://regex101.com/r/dQ4vR2/2)

Comment: This gets me very close.  Adapting for R:

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need some elbow grease and do something like:

```
library(lubridate)

yearEntries <- c("79, 80, 99","07-26-08","07-26-2008","'96  ","Early 70's","93/95","late 70's","15","late 60s","Late 70's",NA,"2013","1992-1993")

x <- yearEntries
x <- gsub("(late|early)", "", x, ignore.case=TRUE)
x <- gsub("[']*[s]*", "", x)
x <- gsub(",.*$", "", x)
x <- gsub(" ", "", x)
x <- ifelse(nchar(x)==9 | nchar(x)<8, gsub("[-/]+[[:digit:]]+$", "", x), x)
x <- ifelse(nchar(x)==4, gsub("^[[:digit:]]{2}", "", x), x)
y <- format(parse_date_time(x, "%m-%d-%y!"), "%y")

yearEntries <-ifelse(!is.na(y), y, x)

yearEntries
##  [1] "79" "08" "08" "96" "70" "93" "70" "15" "60" "70" NA   "13" "92"
```

We have no idea *which* year you need from ranged entries, but this should get you started.

Comment: This gets the job done on this particular example but is not general enough.  The 300 or so "lazy" year entries include all kinds of qualifier words like "around," "about,"  "near as I can reckon," and other weird punctuation.  Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple way to get a good result (though I would not claim it is bullet proof).  It grabs the last readable year, which is okay too.

```
yearEntries <- c("79, 80, 99","07/26/08","07-26-2008","'96  ","Early 70's","93/95","15",NA,"2013","1992-1993","ongoing")
# assume last two digits present in any string represent a 2-digit year 
a<-sub(".*(\\d{2}).*$","\\1",yearEntries)
#  [1] "99"      "08"      "08"      "96"      "70"      "95"      "15"      "ongoing" NA        "13"      "93"   
# change to numeric, strip NAs and add 2000
b<-na.omit(as.numeric(a))+2000
# [1] 2099 2008 2008 2096 2070 2095 2015 2013 2093
# assume any greater than present is last century
b[b>2015]<-b[b>2015]-100
#  [1] 1999 2008 2008 1996 1970 1995 2015 2013 1993
```

...and Bob's your uncle!

Answer (score 0):

@garyth's regex work well actually if you use the `regmatches`/`grexpr`combo to extract the pattern instead of `sub`:

```
regmatches(yearEntries, 
           gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!-|\\/|\\d)|\\d{4}",yearEntries,perl=TRUE))
[[1]]
[1] "79" "80" "99"

[[2]]
[1] "08"

[[3]]
[1] "2008"

[[4]]
[1] "96"

[[5]]
[1] "70"

[[6]]
[1] "95"

[[7]]
[1] "70"

[[8]]
[1] "15"

[[9]]
[1] "60"

[[10]]
[1] "70"

[[11]]
character(0)

[[12]]
[1] "2013"

[[13]]
[1] "1992" "1993"
```

To only keep the first matching pattern:

```
sapply(regmatches(yearEntries,gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!-|\\/|\\d)|\\d{4}",yearEntries,perl=TRUE)),`[`,1)
 [1] "79"   "08"   "2008" "96"   "70"   "95"   "70"   "15"   "60"   "70"   NA     "2013" "1992"
regmatches("07/09/13",gregexpr("(?<!\\d)\\d{2}(?!-|\\/|\\d)|\\d{4}","07/09/13",perl=TRUE))
 [[1]]
 [1] "13"
```